# A functon that finds the numeric letter from the input

Tags: python

I want to define a `get_level(module_info)` return the level of the module in integer. The level is the first numeric letter from the left of the module code.A module code can be `'CS1010S'` .

```
def get_level(module_info):
    return module_info[0][2]
```

However this only work when the `module_info = ('CS1010S', 'A+')` which will give me 1.

What about for when `module_info =('SSA1207', 'B+')` as you can see it will give me `A` instead of `1` which is the output that I want.

Comment: Numeric letter ? Interresting concept :-) Does that go together with the concept of uppercase numbers ? :-)

Comment: Ah! I'll run.  Need to shop for _numeric letters_ before those are out of stock.

Comment: @Bartdude if you casefold an uppercase number, does it convert to roman numeral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best-performance approach, but it's understandable and works:

```
def get_level(module_info):
    for i in module_info[0]:
        if str.isdigit(i):
            return i
```

**Demo:**

```
print get_level(('CS1010S', 'A+')) # 1
print get_level(('SSA1207', 'B+')) # 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the first character of a string that is of a certain type (in this case a digit). `str.isdigit` tests a character and returns `True` if and only if that character is a digit.

With this, you can use `itertools.dropwhile` to drop every leading character of your string that is not a digit, and then pick up the first character (which will therefore be a digit), which is what you want:

```
In [110]: import itertools

In [111]: next(itertools.dropwhile(lambda s: not s.isdigit(), 'SSA1207'))
Out[111]: '1'

In [112]: next(itertools.dropwhile(lambda s: not s.isdigit(), 'CS1010S'))
Out[112]: '1'

In [113]: next(itertools.dropwhile(lambda s: not s.isdigit(), 'CS2010S'))
Out[113]: '2'
```

Comment: You want to _help_ the OP, no?

Comment: @devnull: was adding the explanation as you commented. Check it out ;]

Comment: Yeah, saw that.  I wish you could present, if possible, a more _basic_ approach.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
def get_level(module_info):
    return next(c for c in module_info[0] if c.isdigit())
```

after which:

```
>>> get_level(('CS1010S', 'A+'))
'1'
>>> get_level(('SSA1207', 'B+'))
'1'
>>> get_level(('M9', 'C-'))
'9'
```

`next` is a handy built-in function which gets the next element of something iterable, and `(c for c in module_info[0] if c.isdigit())` is a generator expression which produces all the digits in `module_info[0]` when iterated.  For example:

```
>>> module_info = (('SSA1207', 'B+'))
>>> list(c for c in module_info[0] if c.isdigit())
['1', '2', '0', '7']
```

If there aren't any digits, `next` will raise a `StopIteration`, but you could pass it a default value if you really wanted, e.g.

```
next((c for c in module_info[0] if c.isdigit()), None)
```